# Flutter : How to get the value of the other properties from a List?

Tags: arrays, json, list, flutter

All of my Json data is already inside in my model. And I have also a list of data inside "selectedBranches[]". What do I want is to get the other value of the other properties which is the BranchCode and BranchId based on the value from the selectedBranches list and put it to the another list.
My selectedBranches List is consist  of list of branchFullName properties from my json data.
But dart says The argument type 'List' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Pattern'.

```
#Code Snippet#    
selectedBranches = [ex1,ex2,ex3,ex4];
selectedAssignBranches = [];

assignBranch() {
        branchModel1 = GetBranchList.fromJson(jsonData1);
        var newArr = branchModel1.data;
        for (var u in newArr) {
          AssignBranch assignModel = new AssignBranch();
          if (u.branchFullName.contains(selectedBranches/*error*/)) {
            assignModel.BranchCode = u.branchCode;
            assignModel.BranchID = u.brID;
            selectedAssignBranches.add(assignModel);
          }
        }
      }

#Model#
class Datum {
  String branchCode;
  String branchName;
  String stat;
  String brID;
  String branchFullName;
```

Answer (score 0):

I already solve the problem. You just need to have a nested for loop. Thats it!

```
assignBranch() {
    branchModel1 = GetBranchList.fromJson(jsonData1);
    var newArr = branchModel1.data;

    for (var i in selectedBranches) {
      for (var u in newArr) {
        if (u.branchFullName == (i)) {
          AssignBranch assignModel = new AssignBranch();
          assignModel.BranchCode = u.branchCode;
          assignModel.BranchID = u.brID;
          selectedAssignBranches.add(assignModel);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```